# Thank you for your interest / question / inquiry

Tags: word-choice, word-in-context

My friend that I didn't saw for some time sent me a message and asked me "Hello friend, How are you?". What's the most appropriate / acceptable or natural way to answer him if I want to thank him about that he remembered me?

> Hello, I'm fine, thank you very much for your **interest**.
>
> Hello, I'm fine, thank you very much for your **question**.
>
> Hello, I'm fine, thank you very much for your **inquiry**.

Which of the three verbs (or maybe additional ones that you know) is the correct in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is a multiple-choice English examination question, I would go for "*interest*" as it is the most polite and gracious of the options you give; but actually, both the first two options sound very formal and not the sort of thing a native speaker would say to a real friend.

Probably more common and slightly less formal is:

> "I'm fine, thanks for *asking*"

This is normally used genuinely, but when close friends use overly formal speech with one another it can imply aloofness or make a person sound withdrawn. Saying "*thanks for asking*" or similar in a certain tone might sarcastically imply "why didn't you ask how I was sooner?"

The last option "thanks for your *inquiry*" is incorrect, at least in British English. The word "**e**nquiry" is synonymous with asking a question but is even more formal than your other examples. However, what was once an alternative spelling "**i**nquiry" is now almost entirely used for formal investigations, such a "police inquiry".

Comment: They're not MSQs but a reall situation that I came across into. Thank you for the answer. If you add a smiley after "thanks for asking:)" it'll be probably much less suspicious for sarcasm. Do you agree?:)

Comment: @Wittyloquacity Smiley faces make everything better!

Answer (score 1):

They're all quite formal. To a close friend, a simple "thank you" or "thanks" would suffice.

Out of the three, the last is the most formal, while the first two are somewhat equal.